# Read graph into NetworkX from JSON file

Tags: json, networkx

I have downloaded my Facebook data. I got the data in the form of JSON files.

Now I am trying to read these JSON files into NetworkX. I don't find any function to read graph from JSON file into NetworkX.

In another post, found the info related to reading a graph from JSON, where the JSON file was earlier  created from NetworkX using `json.dump()`.

But here in my case I have downloaded the data from Facebook. Is there any function to read graph from JSON file into NetworkX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Pandas tables or Numpy arrays, JSON files has no rigid structure so one can't write a function to convert **any** JSON file to Networkx graph. If you want to construct a graph based on JSON, you should pick all needed info yourself. You can load a file with [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) function, extract all nodes and edges according to your rules and then put them into your graph with [`add_nodes_from`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_nodes_from.html#networkx.Graph.add_nodes_from) and [`add_edges_from`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_edges_from.html#networkx.Graph.add_edges_from) functions.

For [example Facebook JSON file](https://www.sitepoint.com/facebook-json-example/) you can write something like it:

```
import json
import networkx as nx


with open('fbdata.json') as f:
    json_data = json.loads(f.read())

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_nodes_from(
    elem['from']['name']
    for elem in json_data['data']
)
G.add_edges_from(
    (elem['from']['id'], elem['id'])
    for elem in json_data['data']
)

nx.draw(
    G,
    with_labels=True
)
```

And get this graph:

[image]